# How to add titles, axis label, and legend in sagemath?

Tags: python, graphing, sage

I'm currently making some graphs using the online workbook hosted by sagemath.

This is an example of some code I'm making to try and generate a graph:

```
myplot = list_plot(zip(range(20), range(20)), color='red')
myplot2 = list_plot(zip(range(20), [i*2 for i in range(20)]), color='blue')
combined = myplot + myplot2
combined.show()
```

It's very basic -- it's essentially two scatter plots juxtaposed on top of each other.

Is there a way to easily add axis labels, a legend, and optionally a title?

I managed to hack out a solution that lets me add axis labels, but it looks really ugly and stupid.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg 
def make_graph(plot, labels, figsize=6):
    mplot = plot.matplotlib(axes_labels=labels, figsize=figsize)
    mplot.set_canvas(FigureCanvasAgg(mplot))
    subplot = mplot.get_axes()[0]
    subplot.xaxis.set_label_coords(x=0.3,y=-0.12)
    return mplot

a = make_graph(combined, ['x axis label', 'y axis label'])
a.savefig('test.png')
```

Is there an easier way to add axis labels, legend, and a title?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I eventually found [the documentation](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/plot/graphics.html) for sagemath's `Graphics` object.

I had to do it like this:

```
myplot = list_plot(
    zip(range(20), range(20)), 
    color='red', 
    legend_label='legend item 1')

myplot2 = list_plot(
    zip(range(20), [i*2 for i in range(20)]), 
    color='blue', 
    legend_label='legend item 2')

combined = myplot + myplot2

combined.axes_labels(['testing x axis', 'testing y axis'])
combined.legend(True)

combined.show(title='Testing title', frame=True, legend_loc="lower right")
```

I'm not entirely certain why there's no `title` method and why the title has to be specified inside `show` when the axes don't have to be, but this does appear to work.

Comment: As to why the title has to be specified but not axes, I suppose that's just because mathematicians are more used to having axes without titles.  The title option just barely has shown up in Sage - see http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac/ticket/10512 - so we'd be happy to consider enhancements in how to expose that.

Comment: To elaborate, Sage tends to put things about presentation of the plot in `show` (so that includes axes, with `axes=True` the default), while the plot itself and/or specific data points are accessible without actually plotting the plot, if that makes sense.

Comment: you can set and view the settings that will be used later for the `show` command by accessing/modifying the `my_graphics_obj.SHOW_OPTIONS` dictionary.

Comment: For axes labels, maybe `show(myplot,axes_labels=('$x$','$y$'))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of combining everything in a straighforward way, first defining the plot attributes then the data.

```
plus1 = [[1.1,6.7],[5.,20],[1.8,20],[2.3,12],[8.3,20],[29,34]]    
plus2 = [[1.1,8.9],[5,8.9],[3.9,6.7],[3.9,8.9],
            [5.0,12],[6.4,8.9],[1.4,12],[11,8.9],
            [14,12],[18,12]]
p=plot([],figsize=(4,4),title='Stable combinations of damping and segment length',frame=True,axes_labels= ['varPhi (damping)','w (segment length)'])
p += list_plot(plus2,color='blue',legend_label = 'most stable')
p += list_plot(plus1,color='red',legend_label = 'less stable')
show(p)
```

Answer (score -1):

- Axis Labels: `myplot.xlabel("text for x axis")`, `myplot.ylabel("text for y axis")`
- Title: `myplot.title("My super plot")`
- Legend: Add a `label="Fancy plot"` argument to the calls of `plot` and create the legend with `legend()`

See [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) and [there](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) for further explanations.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work -- an exception appeared stating that 'xlabel', 'ylabel', and 'title' weren't members in the Graphics object (which appears to be subtly different from matplotlib).

Comment: Yes, Sage graphics objects are NOT matplotlib ones, though when we save an object (for e.g. viewing) we use mpl there.  This allows us to create things without importing mpl, for instance.